# Yii2 EachValidator doesn't work

Tags: validation, yii2

I have form with array attributes. I tried to use eachValidator, but it doesn't work. To test validator I create simle form, but each rule still doesn't work.
Model:

```
<?php
namespace frontend\models;

use common\models\User;
use yii\base\Model;
use Yii;

class Test extends Model
{
    public $test;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['test'],'each','rule'=>['required']],
        ];
    }
    public function someFunc()
    {


        return null;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public function actionTest()
{
    $model = new Test();
    return $this->render('test', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

View:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;

?>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'test',]); ?>


            <?= $form->field($model, 'test[]')->textInput(['placeholder'=>'test'])->label('Test'); ?>
            <?= $form->field($model, 'test[]')->textInput(['placeholder'=>'test'])->label('Test'); ?>
            <?= $form->field($model, 'test[]')->textInput(['placeholder'=>'test'])->label('Test'); ?>

            <div class="form-group">
                <?= Html::submitButton('Get started', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'signup-button']) ?>
            </div>

        <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Form successfully submitted with empty fields.
I have Yii 2.0.6
Can enybody tell what I'm doing wrong and how can I validate array attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`yii\validators\EachValidator`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-eachvalidator.html) does not validate data on client side, you should simply call `validate()` or `save()` in your controller :

```
public function actionTest()
{
    $model = new Test();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        // do what you want
    }

    return $this->render('test', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation! But now I don't know what to do with ajax. I have very big form. It divided into steps, and next step is added to the end of page after previous submitted. Without client side validation I get duplicate of step with validation errors =(